# Value is not a keyword

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, keyword

I was making typing effect in React and it says Value is not a keyword in the error below.

```
"error : Line 13:33: 'value' is not defined no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error"
```

Here is the code I am using

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const TypeWriter = ({text}) => {
    const index = useRef(0);
    const[currentText, setCurrentText]=useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        index.current=0;
        setCurrentText('');
    },[text]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() =>{
        setCurrentText((value)= value + Text.charAt(index.current));
        index.current+=1;
    },1000);
    return()=> {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    },[currentText,text]);

    return <p>{currentText}</p>;
};

export default TypeWriter;
```

Comment: Typo: `setCurrentText((value)= value + Text.charAt(index.current));` should be `setCurrentText((value)=> value + Text.charAt(index.current));`

Comment: Ohh shitt!  now I am embarrassed Thank you so much @AKX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is this line:

`setCurrentText((value)= value + Text.charAt(index.current));`

setCurrentText needs a function as a parameter, like this instead:

`setCurrentText((value) => value + Text.charAt(index.current))`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the typo, there's no need to keep the truncated text in state; keep the index there instead.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TypeWriter = ({ text }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIndex(0);
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setIndex((index) => index + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [text]);
  const currentText = text.substring(0, index);

  return <p>{currentText}</p>;
};

export default TypeWriter;
```

Comment: I see. Very informative. Thanks @AKX